# Overloading in Java Web Services - Error in JAVA2WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, overloading

I wanted to overload a method in Web Services in Java. Is it possible? To put more detail to it... we already have a method add(int a,int b, int c) exposed, we wanted to expose another method add (int a, int b) for a second application to use. When I try to do a Java2WSDL it gives me an error message - Attempted to write duplicate schema element.
If it is allowed can someone throw light on how to achieve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on not supporting SOAP method overloading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976836/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-not-supporting-soap-method-overloading)

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976836/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-not-supporting-soap-method-overloading